# How do You Inherit a Custom TableViewController For An TableView in a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a custom SwipeCellTableView class that I inherited from when using  UITableViewControllers. Now I want to just use that class for an ib outlet table view controller in a regular View Controller. It is proving to be very difficult and seemingly not worth it anymore. Can this be done?

Here is the superclass which inherits from a TableViewController, I have tried to change it to inherit from a view controller but it just doesn't work out

```
class SwipeTableViewController: UITableViewController, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {

var cell: UITableViewCell?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = 80.0
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
    guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

    let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
        // handle action by updating model with deletion
        self.updateModel(at: indexPath)
    }

    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete-icon")

    return [deleteAction]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
    var options = SwipeTableOptions()
    options.expansionStyle = .destructive
    //options.transitionStyle = .reveal
    return options
}

func updateModel(at indexPath: IndexPath){
    //update data model
    print("Item deleted from super class")
}
```

Here is the View Controller I'm trying to access it from:

```
class GoalsViewController: UIViewController, SwipeTableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var categoryTable: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

@IBAction func addCategoryPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showgoalsSeg", sender: self)
}
```

For reference on how I was using it before when using an actual TableViewController:

```
class CategoryViewController: SwipeTableViewController {

var categories: Results<Category>? //optional so we can be safe

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadCategory()
    tableView.rowHeight = 80.0
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
}
//MARK: - Tableview Datasource Methods
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Only get the count of categories if it's nil, else 1
    return categories?.count ?? 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //fetching cell from super view
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = categories?[indexPath.row].name ?? "No Categories Added Yet"



    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: categories?[indexPath.row].color ?? "000000")

    return cell
}


//MARK: - Tableview Delegate Methods
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToItems", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ToDoListViewController

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destinationVC.selectedCategory = categories?[indexPath.row]
    }
}
//MARK: - Add New Categories

@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    var textField = UITextField()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Category", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Category", style: .default) { (action) in

        let newCategory = Category()
        newCategory.name = textField.text!
        newCategory.color = UIColor.randomFlat.hexValue()

        self.save(category: newCategory)
    }
    alert.addAction(action)

    alert.addTextField { (field) in
        textField = field
        textField.placeholder = "Add a new category"
    }
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func save(category: Category){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    do {
        try realm.write{
            realm.add(category)
        }
    } catch {
        print("error saving context")
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func updateModel(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    super.updateModel(at: indexPath)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    if let categoryForDeletion = self.categories?[indexPath.row]{
        do{
            try realm.write{
                realm.delete(categoryForDeletion)
            }
        } catch {
            print("error deleting cell")
        }
        //tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

func loadCategory(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    categories = realm.objects(Category.self)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Is this even worth persuing? Or doable?

Comment: you can set your outlet tableview delegate and datasource to instance of SwipeTableViewController

Comment: @SPatel how do I override or access the classes from my custom class?